# How would you remove "0"s from the middle of elements in an array

Tags: javascript

I am creating a table sorter and to sort a column full of items that have both letters and numbers (e.g. thing 027) I added zeros to the beginning of the numbers to make it so I can sort them. So where my question comes in is I want to remove the zeros from the numbers so that it looks cleaner. This is my code:

```
for (var kneecap = 0; kneecap < bronze.length; kneecap++) {
            if(isNaN(bronze[kneecap]) === false && bronze[kneecap] === "0"){
                if (bronze[kneecap - 1] != 1 && bronze[kneecap - 1] != 2 && bronze[kneecap - 1] != 3 && bronze[kneecap - 1] != 4 && bronze[kneecap - 1] != 5 && bronze[kneecap - 1] != 6 && bronze[kneecap - 1] != 7 && bronze[kneecap - 1] != 8 && bronze[kneecap - 1] != 9) {
                    bronze[kneecap] = "";
                }
```

where bronze is each element in the array that contains each of the letters/numbers. This code works but it is really ugly and I really hate it. I was hoping someone could give me a better way to write this code.

With this little snip-it of code it is probably hard to fully understand my problem so here is a link to my full [code](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ4St/9/). (not the full table sorter just the part where I remove the zeros).

Comment: Why not sort it properly without adding the zeroes in the first place.  if you show your sort code, we can help you fix that.

Comment: Are you using completely random words for variable names? Bronze? Kneecap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it looks like you have an array of strings that have leading zero numbers embeded in them.  I would recommend using `.replace()`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < solely_combined.length; i++) {
    solely_combined[i] = solely_combined[i].replace(/0+(\d+)/g, "$1");
}
```

Working demo using your actual array: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MJQY4/

The regular expression is as follows:

```
/    - start of a regular expression
0+   - one or more zeros
(    - start of a group
\d+  - one or more digits
)    - end of a group
/    - end of a regular expression
g    - "g" flag on the regular expression which means to replace all occurrences
$1   - replace what is found with the first group in the match
```

So, in total the regular expression:

```
/0+(\d+)/
```

is one or more zeroes followed by one or more digits

And then the entire match is replaced by just what matched inside the parens, leaving the leading zeroes out of the replacement (effectively removing the leading zeroes).

There are a zillion sites on the internet for learning regular expressions.  I use [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am shocked at how simple your code is compared to mine. The "(/0+(\d+)/g, "$1")" just baffled me, where can I learn this level of coding?

Comment: That's a "regular expression".  There are millions of sites on the internet that help you learn regular expressions and/or even practice them.  I use [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as a reference.  More detailed description of the regular expression added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [2, 5, 0];
var index = array.indexOf(0);
```

Then remove it with splice:

```
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```